# Vue component not updating/rerendering

Tags: vue.js

In my vue component data I got an object `routine` with other nested objects.

I have this method:

```
methods: {
    async loadFullRoutine() {
        const routine = await this.$store.dispatch('loadPresetsForRoutine', this.routine);
        console.log(this.routine);
        // routine.name = routine.name + '!';
    }
},
```

In the `loadPresetsForRoutine` action in my vuex store, a nested object of the `routine` object get changed but the changes are not being rendered. When I look at the `console.log` I can see that the `routine` object is being updated properly.
When I do `routine.name = routine.name + '!';`, the component is being rerendered with the updated data from `loadPresetsForRoutine`.

Any Ideas?

Comment: might be considered a bit of a hack, but you can try to force the update after dispatching the routine.      this.$nextTick(()=>{
        this.$forceUpdate();
      })

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your component? There's not enough information to debug the problem.